# New record is not registered but still displays new record added successfully

Tags: php, mysql

I am adding a new group to groups panel when I enter given credentials it shows record added successfully but when i check it in MYSQL database there is nothing added. This is the code:

```
<?php 
extract($_POST);
if(isset($save))
{

$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from groups where group_name='$g_name' or registration_number='$reg_no'");
$r=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if($r!=true)
        {
        mysqli_query($conn,"insert into groups values('','$g_name','$region','$district','$division','$ward','$village','$reg_no','$activity','$category','$members','$leader','$loan','$capital',now())");

$err="<font color='blue'>Congrates new Group added successfully</font>";
        }

        else
        {

    $err="<font color='red'>This Group name or Registration number already exists choose diff group name</font>";


    }
}

?>
```

These are the scripts for filling the form:

```
<script src="add_group.js"></script>
<h2 style="color:#00FFFF;text-decoration:underline;" align="center">Add New Group</h2>
<form method="post">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><?php echo @$err;?></div>
    </div>
```

Enter group name:

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Enter Group Name</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="g_name" pattern="[a-z A-Z]*" class="form-control" required/></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Enter Registration Number</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="reg_no" class="form-control" required/></div>
    </div>
```

Select Activity:

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Group Activity</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="activity" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">Select Activity</option>
            <option>Activity 1</option>
            <option>Activity 2</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Select Category:

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Group Category</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="category" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">Select Group Category</option>
            <option>Group of men only </option>
            <option>Group of women only</option>
            <option>Group of both men and women</option>
            <option>Group of youth only</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Total members:

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Group Total Members</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" class="form-control" name="members"  />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Group Leader Name</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" pattern="[a-z A-Z]*" class="form-control" name="leader" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Loan Information</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="loan"  />
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Group Capital</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" class="form-control" name="capital"  required/>
        </div>
    </div>  



    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Select Region</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select onchange="showDistrict(this.value)"  name="region" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">Select Region</option>
            <?php 
$region=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from region");
while($reg1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($region))
{?>
<option value="<?php echo $reg1['region_id'];?>"><?php echo $reg1['region_name'];?></option>
<?php 
}
            ?>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Select District</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="district" onchange="showDivision(this.value)" id="district" class="form-control" >
            <option value="">Select District</option>   
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Select Division</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="division" onchange="showWard(this.value)"  id="division" class="form-control" >
            <option value="">Select Division</option>   
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Select Ward</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="ward" onchange="showVillage(this.value)" id="ward" class="form-control" >
            <option value="">Select Ward</option>   
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-4">Select Village</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="village" id="village"  class="form-control" >
            <option value="">Select Village</option>    
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">


<input type="submit" value="Add New Group" name="save" class="btn btn-success"/>
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is database table:

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| group_id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| group_name          | char(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| region              | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| district            | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| division            | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ward                | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| village             | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| registration_number | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_activity      | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_category      | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_total_members | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_leader        | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| loan_information    | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_capital       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_creation_date | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: This `if($r!=true)` should be `if($r > 0)` `mysqli_num_rows: Returns number of rows in the result set.`

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to use the extract function on user defined input such as $_GET, $_POST etc. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

You did not include the code for connecting to database. Is the $conn variable a valid connection object?.

You have set the group_id field value to empty. This field is of type integer and its value cannot be null. You should remove it from the query. Its value will be auto generated

As I understand you want to insert data to database only if it does not exist already. The insert sql query should include the field names.